# How can I show up the errors in Laravel when response is 500?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application working on different urls. example.ch and app.example.net are working will. On the same server like app.example.net i like to run app-stage.example.net.

The application return an error 500 without an error log.

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
var_dump($kernel); // returns an object. Everything ok
```

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

var_dump($response) //returns error 500
```

I checked the php version.
I checked the fpm version.
I checked the .env file
I did "sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage"
I restarted the server.
I tried to show the errors.

```
error_reporting(-1); // reports all errors
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // shows all errors
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
```

No success.

What can I do in addition to find the error?

Comment: check your server logs (apache nginx or other) usualy when it's a 500, the error is out of reach of the code. (500 Internal Server Error )

Answer (score 0):

use this package [Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

make a file like this  [image: Dotenv working in my system]

and then use multiple .env for example acceptnace.env . production.env , staging.env

### make a file like environment.php in bootstrap directory like this

```
<?php

$envPath = realpath(dirname(__DIR__));

$env = get_current_user();
if ($env == 'staging') {
    $envFile = ".staging.env";
} elseif ($env == "acceptance") {
    $envFile = ".acceptance.env";
} elseif ($env == "development") {
    $envFile = ".development.env";
} elseif ($env == "production") {
    $envFile = ".production.env";
} elseif ($env == "beta") {
    $envFile = ".beta.env";
} else {
    $envFile = ".local.env";
}
Dotenv\Dotenv::create($envPath, $envFile)->load();
```

and this will load multiple env for your app